# Hiding link in java script using style=none does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

I am trying to hide some links using Java script `style.display = 'none'` property.It works fine in all browsers.But not in IE.Please suggest me some alternate for below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var copyLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-copy');
    if(copyLinks != null && copyLinks != undefined){
        for(i = 0; i < (copyLinks.length); i++) {
            copyLinks[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: try element.fadeOut(); / element.hide();  or element.css('display', 'none');

Comment: @AramilRey he's not using jQuery, and even if he was, both of those commands just set the display property to none

Comment: Can you recreate it in a fiddle? It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Display: none works in IE6-10 – without any form of bugs. If it’s not working in a specific browser, there is either a syntax problem, or you’re applying a style to that browser specifically somehow (IE7 stylesheet?)
You must check the version of it and what stylesheet it used in real.
I think it didn't match in someway. IE's really a big trouble with DEV 
:D

Answer (score 0):

The Problem might be with getElementsByClassName.

You Can try Below JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $(".icon-copy").hide();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @user1770589 I tried it in IE9, its working fine. Here is a fiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/9gg6pts8/4/..
Please Share your HTML Code also, I guess there might b some mistake.